# Why cursor doesn't change on the button

Tags: html, css

I am not sure why the cursor doesn't change to the pointer on the button. I see some solutions saying it is because of the `z-index`. But when I tried with `z-index`, still it doesn't work.

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

Thanks for any help.

I am cheating from this codepen:

https://codepen.io/adambene/pen/xRWrXN

Comment: you have to add `cursor: pointer;` property in .btn class.

Comment: Thanks but I have tried that too.

Comment: Well, in chrome it works with `.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {cursor: pointer; }` - Not sure why

Comment: Yes. But then it doesn't work with Firefox.

Comment: @Stackedup In FF it should work just fine with `.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {cursor: pointer; }` (I've checked) Note that in your fiddle there's no `cursor` style for the file input

Comment: @Stackedup you are not defining the button type. I think if you will use `<button type="button">Upload a file</button>` then it will work fine in FF.

Comment: @Stackedup Check this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZdrYGO Should work for both FF and Chrome

Comment: @AlonEitan, yes this works. Thank you so much. Please post. I mark it as answer.

Comment: I have to go so I invite you to write your own answer and self-accept it :) Glad to help

Comment: @Stackedup Check my solution, it works perfectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make these changes to the input:

1. Add [`cursor: pointer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor).
2. Add [`width: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width) and [`height: 100%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height).
3. Change [`font-size: 100px`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size) to [`font-size: 0`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size).

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

Comment: @Stackedup it's strange. This works for me in Firefox and Chrome on macOS.

Comment: Not sure why. On chrome on windows 10 doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @Stackedup I changed `font-size: 100px` to `font-size: 0`, seems to work well in Chrome on Windows.

Comment: Awesome thanks. This also works. Now we have two solution. I posted one below on behalf of Alon as well. I mark this as solution.

Answer (score 6):

Try adding `cursor: pointer;` property to the input type of file.
Here's the final snippet for the input type of file.

```
.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer; /*this is what you need*/
}
```

Let me know if that works or not.

Comment: Sorry it just went missing. I had tried that already. I updated the problem to reflect this.

Comment: I assume you are following this codepen, https://codepen.io/adambene/pen/xRWrXN I added the one line as I mentioned about and it is working just fine. On which browser you are checking though?

Comment: strange. I am doing it as well. No luck.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change the `font-size 100%` to `font-size 0` and add `width:100%;height:100%` to the input file to take the entier button

```
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
      font-size: 0;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      opacity: 0;
      cursor: pointer;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Credits go to @Alon (also thanks to everyone):

```
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

With the following CSS works on both FireFox and Chrome:

```
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
  }

  .btn {
    border: 2px solid gray;
    color: gray;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 8px 20px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file]::-webkit-file-upload-button {cursor: pointer; }

  .upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
    font-size: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Its working fine. please check it out

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  text-indent: -999px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
**.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file]   {
  font-size: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
}**
```

Answer (score 0):

please try it out

```css
.upload-btn-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.btn {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  color: gray;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 8px 20px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.upload-btn-wrapper input[type=file] {
  font-size: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
  <button class="btn">Upload a file</button>
  <input type="file" name="myfile" />
</div>
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks @Irin. Also thanks everyone else for your help.

Comment: How is that solution working? It doesn't do anything when you click on the "Upload a file" area, only when you click under the visible button. This answer is wrong (At least for the Chrome browser)

Comment: Oh yes. I just noticed it too. Sorry.

Comment: let me fix this for you. I can fix it